# Crm 2011 serverProxy object disposed with integration application

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We have an integration application to upload data from SQL server tables to Dynamics CRM 2011 by using web services. (CRM 2011 on premise)

This integration application uses multi threads. For example, when i upload 2.5 million data, it goes well until about 1 million record, but after that, it gets errors such as

```
> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
> party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail
```

and after that, serviceproxy seems disposed.

Anything to do to get rid of this?

searching google,it show same result about religion settings but its no solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of authentication are you using? If it's claims-based, it's possible that the auth token is expiring. If this is the case, you can either increase the time that the token is valid for (I believe the default is 60 minutes), or you can check the token for expiration before you make a call to the service and refresh when necessary. More details in [this best practices doc from the CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509027.aspx#Performance).